# How do I install {biz}strap to my Rails app on my Local Machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

Does anybody know how I can install {biz}strap http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0025522 from {wrap}bootstrap https://wrapbootstrap.com/ ?Or of any instructional guide to do the installation of the this theme.I want to eventually push the app to Heroku.Thanks in advance :D!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried copying the file to the public folder of your rails app?

Comment: Yes!!So, what I have done is create a new rails app, and unzip the {biz}strap theme template.Copied all the unzipped files and pasted them in the public folder.Nothing seems to be working.But I'll try to move the theme's assets files into the app assets and see what happens.Let me know if you have any other ideas of how to go about solving this.Thanks in advance :D!!!